# How to Make A Countdown Timer And Update MySQL Record When The Time is Up?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, timer, countdown

I need help on how to update MySQL table when time is up? I got this code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var timeleft;
var nextdue;
var tick = 1000;
function parseTime(t) {
    var tt = ("0:00:" + t);
    tt = tt.split(":").reverse();
    return (tt[0] * 1000) + (tt[1] * 60000) + (tt[2] * 3600000);
}
function zeroPad(n) {
    if (n < 10) return "0" + n;
    return "" + n;
}


function makeTime(t) {
    if (t < 0) return "0:00:00";
    var tt = t + 999;
    return Math.floor(tt / 3600000) + ":" +
        zeroPad(Math.floor(tt / 60000) % 60) + ":" +
        zeroPad(Math.floor(tt / 1000) % 60);
}

function startTimer() {
    nextdue = new Date().getTime();
    timeleft = parseTime(document.timerform.timerbox.value);
    runTimer();
}

function runTimer() {
    document.timerform.timerbox.value = makeTime(timeleft);
    if (timeleft <= 0) alert("Time's up!");
    else {
        var timecorr = (new Date().getTime()) - nextdue;
        if (timecorr > 0 && timecorr < 3000) {
            timeleft -= (tick + timecorr);
            nextdue += tick;
            if (timeleft < 1) setTimeout("runTimer()", tick + timeleft);
            else setTimeout("runTimer()", Math.max(1, tick - timecorr));
        }
        else {
            nextdue = (new Date().getTime()) + tick;
            timeleft -= tick;
            if (timeleft < 1) setTimeout("runTimer()", tick + timeleft);
            else setTimeout("runTimer()", tick);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And, it works when I place a PHP variable to load the time; but, I want to use it like the following:

- when it reaches `0` seconds, I want it to update mySQL table and then come back to same page.

Is this possible? Thank you. This is my first time here.

Comment: Make PHP script that will do database stuff and then call it with ajax call when your counter reaches zero. With ajax you can also pass some parameters if needed.

Comment: I take it "he.lp" is to avoid the bad title filter? If so, please don't do this - questions do not need to ask for help, since it is implicit (and asking it explicitly can sound like begging, so it is definitely best avoided).

Comment: If you are not familar with AJAX this link may be helpful: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Comment: Thank you i will see the Ajax

Comment: but is there a way to just add something like window.location.href="<the page you are going to>"; to this code when it reach 0

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a library such as jQuery, or a framework such as Backbone.js to make your life a little bit easier in handling javascript tasks.

To do what you want (if I'm understanding the question correctly), you would need something like the following. In the following example, I will assume you have jquery included in your webpage.

```
/* 
 * Your time-tracking code here 
*/

// If the time left is 0 seconds/milliseconds/whatever
if(time_left === 0) {
    // then do an AJAX request to the server page that handles updating the mysql table
    $.ajax({
        type: operation, // (GET, POSt, etc)
        url: url, // The location of your php file relative to your root URL
        data: {}, // the data you want the server (php file) to receive
        success: function(data){
            // Whatever you want to happen when the server succeeds with the operation
        }
    });
}
```

In your php file you would simply have a function that updates your table as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Hi every one i found it thank you, this is the answer to my question
when time reach 0 goes to this page then it returns to same page and repeats until no more time. coool. thank again

```
if (timeleft<=0)window.location.href="./mod.php";
```